# Don't loop again until completed

Tags: node.js, loops

In my app, is there a way that I can make a while loop not go through unless everything inside it has been ran through once? This is what I'm doing:

```js
while (runs > 0) {
  message.channel.send("run")
  await collector.on('collect', async msg => {
        if (msg.content.startsWith("success")) {
          succeeds += 1
        }
        runs -= 1
      }
```

If I have runs set to 10, each time the if statement got triggered it adds to succeeds variable. At the end when its done, `console.log(succeeds)` shows 18-22 instead.

The point of this while loop is to have it execute something x times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use async/await and promises to make your while loop wait.
Use the resolve of promise to make your single iteration pause.

```
const waitingWhileFunction = async () => {
  let runs = 10;
  while (run > 0) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      collector.on('collect', (msg) => {
        if (msg.content.startsWith('success')) {
          succeeds += 1;
        }
        resolve();
      });
    });
    runs -= 1;
  }
};

waitingWhileFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch error inside the loop so that it doesn't break. Example:

```
let loop = true;
while(loop) {
  try {
    // do something 1
    // do something 2
    // do something N
    loop = false;
  } catch(e) {
    // Did not succeed. Run again
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, that might work. The problem is that I'm making it add 1 to a variable if the response is "true" and when its true it gets added on 2-3 times instead of once.